# Remove special characters Replace the characters < > / | " : ; ? * , ! = | but maintain font color for each word

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through all cells in Column D<G,I and remove and value that containing Space after last word in cell and/or ant special character such as  < > / | " : ; ? * , ! = |.
the problem i am facing with my code if any cell have different word with different font color it removes font color after triming or replacing such as Trim or Replace

```
Public Function cleanTemplateRange(FloorT As Long, BaseT As Long, WallT As Long)
    
   Dim dirtyRange As Range
    ' Set the dirtyRange to the specific columns you want to clean
     Set dirtyRange = Union(Sheets("template").Range("D2:D" & FloorT), Sheets("template").Range("G2:G" & BaseT), Sheets("template").Range("I2:I" & WallT))
    
    Set oRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    If oRegex Is Nothing Then Set oRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With oRegex
        .Global = True
        ' Allow A-Z, a-z, 0-9, a space, and a hyphen -
        '.Pattern = "[^\w .-""']"
        
    ' Replace the characters < > / | " : ; ? * , ! = | except .
        .Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9 .-]"
    End With
    
    Dim cleanCell As Range
    For Each cleanCell In dirtyRange
     'DoEvents
        cleanCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(oRegex.Replace(cleanCell.Value, vbNullString))
    Next cleanCell
    
    Set cleanRoomsRange = dirtyRange
    
End Function
```

Comment: You'll have to loop over the characters in each cell.

Comment: Once you set the cell's `Value` then any per-character formatting is wiped out.